# UITableView with multiple viewcontollers

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xib

I just filled my UITableView with Planets. I would like each cell clicked to open into a new Xib (if this sounds like the wrong approach please direct). I can get a secondviewcontroller working, its getting the thirdviewcontroller and fourthviewcontroller working? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code from your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method? If you can get the second view controller working, then the rest should work similarly.

Comment: Check out UINavigationController.  It's designed for this.

Answer (score 1):

Place your main view controller (the one with the table) inside a UINavigationController. Then, when the user selects a row, push a new view controller onto it.

Answer (score 1):

The following function will help. As Ben Gottlieb said your main view controller will need to be in a UINavigationController.  You need to implement the delegate method for didSelectRowAtIndexPath and this is where you create the new controller for your new view and load it.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        YourViewController *controller =  [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController"bundle:nil];         
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES];   
        [yourViewController release]; // don't leak memory
        }
```

Based on the row number you can decide which nib to load.

Comment: Thanks Neilngils and Ben. I play around with it and added a IF statement, not sure if this is the correct approach but it works.
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  int RowCount = [indexPath row];
  if (RowCount == 0){  
   EarthViewController *earthViewController =  [[EarthViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EarthViewController"bundle:nil];         
   [[self navigationController] pushViewController:earthViewController animated:YES];   
   [earthViewController release]; // don't leak memory
 }
  else if (RowCount ==1){ .....